# Date range filter for questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering

I was recently looking for why there was a *really* sudden influx of questions on Meta.SO around July 20ish, 2016 (the following graph should indicate why I was looking for it), and I was forced to click through 100+ pages of questions before finding the reason. (I forgot Documentation released then, lots of bug reports and feature requests.)

[image: Graph of influx]

Could we get a date-range filter on the sites? (Or at least SO) It gets *really* annoying to have to click through 100+ pages of questions to finally find the time-frame I'm looking for, I can't be the *only* user who would find this helpful.

Comment: "You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:

    `created:` to specify when the posts were created..." ([Help Center > Our model > How do I search?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching))

Comment: @gnat Then perhaps the simplest solution is to add that to the 'Advanced Search Tips' display, because it's *not* there at all.

Comment: laugh if you wish but I get there right from 'Advanced Search Tips' display - at the bottom of it there is a notice "For more details on advanced search [visit our help page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)"

Comment: @gnat I'd never click that link in my life, ever. I assume if it's not in 'advanced search tips' then it doesn't exist.

Comment: neither did I (this time it only happened because I already knew there is such an operator because someone has shown me it in the past). They have done something really wrong in UX since this reference is so easy to miss

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/622761?start=2016-07-01&end=2016-07-30) for this?

Comment: @rene *Maybe*, but that requires a bit of SQL whereas I could just write one search query and take a quick glance at the results. (I didn't really care *what* the results were, I figured the question tags would tell me and they did.)

Answer (score 3):

Dates can be entered in the following formats:

---

#### Absolute Dates

| Stack Exchange Search Parameter Language | English |
| --- | --- |
| `created:2012..2013` | Fetch posts **created** from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013 |
| `created:2012` | Search for posts **created** from January 1, **2012** through December 31, **2012** |
| `created:2012-04..2012-05` | searches posts created between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012 |
| `lastactive:2012-04-03` | give me posts which were last active between 12:00 AM on April 3, 2012 and 11:59 PM on April 3, 2012. |
| `created:1y` | give me everything going back one year. |
| `created:1m` | give me or display all posting which were posted less than one month ago. |
| `created:1d` | show me all the stuff made between the present time and the present time less one day or 24 hours. |
| `created:14d` | show me all the stuff made between the present time and the present time less 14 days. |
| `lastactive:3m..` | On April 15, `lastactive:3m..` will show postings from January 15 up to the most recently active posting. |
| `lastactive:3m..1m` | please press the edit button and edit this post to have an English description here. |

For any whole number **x** You can write `created:xd` to look back **x** number of days.